# how to get images from server efficently in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am having 5000 images as thumbnails of videos and it has to be shown in the table view, what is the best way of done it?? Please help me.

Comment: Try this http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-add-uiimage-and-uilabel-in-the-uitableview/

Comment: Yeah... Scar is right Use Lazy Loading concept for data downloading in tableview and its sample also available on net.

Comment: There's `LazyTableImages` concept by Apple, there's also `SDWebImages` library I'd suggest to use instead of Apple's standard loading class. The question is - what have you tried?

Comment: mate,
just follow the code of bellow link.. http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/ just take AsynchImageView with downloading image in background.. :)

Comment: he is asking to display lot of images.....

Comment: Well i have done using lazy loading ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Lazy Loading concept, take a look at the apple [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) for demonstrate a lazy loading `UITableView`.

**Update**

This is in case of using a server side for hosting the images (which is a best solution for your app cause it's wrong to save a huge number of images (5000 image) in the app.

Comment: yeh that is right but the scenario is to get only 10 images first time in table and then another 10 as the scrolled down the server respond wih another 10 which append to the Mutable array.